# Binding to ObservableCollection populated from XML not working

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Using Blend.

I am trying to bind either a GridView or TextBlock to an Observable collection. The observable collection gets its data from an XML file. My test program runs, but no data appears in the GridView or the TextBlock when I press the 'Show Sentence' button.

My XML file:

(Simlpified from a large and complex file which works OK in a Visual Studio console project)

```
<Book ISBN ="9144252184178">
  <Title>
    <TitleLine>Title First Line</TitleLine>
    <TitleLine>Title Second Line</TitleLine>
  </Title>
  <Authors>
    <Author>Some Body</Author>
    <Author>No Body</Author>
  </Authors>
  <Pages>
    <Page PageNumber ="1">
      <Sentences>
        <Sentence SentenceID = "1">
          <SentenceText>Once there was a giant </SentenceText>
          <SentenceFileName>9144252184178.1.1</SentenceFileName>
          <SentenceWords>
            <SentenceWord Start = "" Part = "">once</SentenceWord>
            <SentenceWord Start = "" Part = "">there</SentenceWord>
            <SentenceWord Start = "" Part = "">was</SentenceWord>
            <SentenceWord Start = "" Part = "">a</SentenceWord>
            <SentenceWord Start = "" Part = "">giant</SentenceWord>
          </SentenceWords>
        </Sentence>
        <Sentence SentenceID = "2">
          <SentenceText>Every day, etc</SentenceText>
          <SentenceFileName>9144252184178.1.2</SentenceFileName>
          <SentenceWords>
            <SentenceWord Start = "" Part = "">every</SentenceWord>
            <SentenceWord Start = "" Part = "">day</SentenceWord>
            <SentenceWord Start = "" Part = "">etc</SentenceWord>
          </SentenceWords>
        </Sentence>
      </Sentences>
    </Page>
  </Pages>
</Book>
```

MainPage.xaml:

(Showing a couple of the many ways I have unsuccessfully tried to bind to the ObservableCollection)

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Show Sentence" Click="button_Click"/>
    <GridView Background="Bisque" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ThisSentence}">
      <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Sentences">
          <StackPanel Background="AliceBlue">
            <TextBlock Text="Sentence"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind SentenceID}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind SentenceText}"/>
           </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
    <Border Background="LightBlue">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThisSentence.SentenceID, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </Border>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace ImportFromXML
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Book> thisSentence_;
        public ObservableCollection<Book> ThisSentence
        {
            get { return thisSentence_; }
            set { thisSentence_ = value; }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           var newTask = Task.Run(() => thisSentence_ = SentenceManager.GetSentence("0","0")) ;
           DataContext = ThisSentence;
        }
    }
}
```

Book.cs:

(Here are my classes and my SentenceManager. The SentenceManager Linq code works against my XML when run in a VS Console project.)

```
public class Book
{
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public IList<Title> title = new List<Title>();
    public IList<Authors> authors = new List<Authors>();
    public IList<Pages> pages = new List<Pages>();
}

public class Title
{
    public string TitleLine { get; set; }
}

public class Authors
{
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
}

public class Pages
{
    public string PageNumber { get; set; }
    public IList<Sentences> sentences = new List<Sentences>();
    public IList<Contents> contents = new List<Contents>();
 }

public class Sentences
{
    public string SentenceID { get; set; }
    public string SentenceText { get; set; }
    public string SentenceFileName { get; set; }
    public IList<SentenceWords> sentenceWords = new List SentenceWords>();
}

public class SentenceWords
{
    public string SentenceWord { get; set; }
    public string Ending { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
}


public class SentenceManager
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Book> GetSentence(string pageNumber, string sentenceID)
    {

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Richard\Documents\ImportFromXML\book.xml");
        List<Book> sentence = (from bk in xdoc.Elements("Book")
                               select new Book
                               {
                                 pages = (from pag in bk.Element("Pages").Elements("Page")
                                          where (string)pag.Attribute("PageNumber") == pageNumber
                                          select new Pages
                                           {
                                             sentences = (from sen in pag.Element("Sentences").Elements("Sentence")
                                                          where (string)sen.Attribute("SentenceID") == sentenceID
                                                          select new Sentences
                                                          {
                                                            SentenceID = sen.Attribute("SentenceID").Value,
                                                            SentenceText = sen.Element("SentenceText").Value,
                                                            SentenceFileName = sen.Element("SentenceFileName").Value,
                                                          }).ToList(),
                                            }).ToList(),
                               }).ToList();

        ObservableCollection <Book> Sentence = new ObservableCollection<Book>(sentence);
        return Sentence;
    }
}
```

In my program I have to bind a number of controls to various parts of my xml data, so this is just one example.

I am a bit of a novice, so please don't make your advice too cryptic or I may not understand! Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you bind to the `ThisSentence` property by `x:Bind` like

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind ThisSentence}"
```

it is not necessary to set the `DataContext` at all.

However, the binding mode has to be set to `OneWay`, because the default is `OneTime`:

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind ThisSentence, Mode=OneWay}"
```

In addition, the property has to notify about value changes. In a class derived from DependencyObject, this is usually done by making it a dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ThisSentenceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ThisSentence",
        typeof(MainPage),
        typeof(ObservableCollection<Book>),
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

public ObservableCollection<Book> ThisSentence
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Book>)GetValue(ThisSentenceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ThisSentenceProperty, value); }
}
```

You should also await the Task in the Click handler.

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ThisSentence = await Task.Run(() => SentenceManager.GetSentence("0", "0"));
}
```

Note that event handlers are the exception to the rule that there shouldn't be any `async void` methods.

---

In case you want to use `Binding` instead of `x:Bind`, you should set the DataContext once in the Page's constructor, like

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Now you could also write

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ThisSentence}"
```

Comment: I have implemented both suggestions, but still get nothing in either the GridView or TextBlock.

Comment: Setting the DataContext wasn't necessary at all. See the edited answer.

Comment: I am getting an error on typeof(MainWindow). The Type or Namespace name 'MainWindow, could not be found.

Comment: Sure, change that to MainPage (as I already did in the answer).

Comment: Now I get an error:An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in ImportFromXML.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

Comment: Error occurs at: set { SetValue(ThisSentenceProperty, value); }

Comment: Yes, because it was called in an async Task. I've changed the `button_Click` implementation.

Comment: Did you try `Binding` instead of `x:Bind`?

Comment: Yes. Same problem. And I want to bind some controls to other ObservableCollections on the same page which I guess is not possible if the DataCiontext is set at initialisation? maybe I will need to use multiple views on one collection?

Comment: Now I am getting an error: Unable to cast object of type 'ImportFromXML.Models.Book' to type 'ImportFromXML.Models.Sentences'.

Comment: I guess that's outside the scope of this question. I can't fix all of your code.

Comment: How true. Thanks for your patience and help.